# Referencing to specific class from different page

Tags: css, shopify-template

Using Shopify to run a site. Have limitations on the platform.

Want to specifically style a class that's tag to a specific ID inside a div.

div class pplr-wrapper is repeated pages to pages. However div id & data-id are unique from pages to pages, thus targeting specifically.
[image: Reference]

Tried styling it with the CSS code below

```
div#1947011350631 div.pplr-wrapper.pplr-power-supply span[ class^="pplr-drop-item _pplr_1.6_kilowatt_evga"] {
color: red;
}
```

Not able to make any changes with it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but this answer assumes that you want to target the `span` only when it's inside that unique id.

That looks like a un-necessary long selector (and I think your error might be that you have a space inside the attribute selector (`span[ class` should be `span[class`), but I think you could reduce the selector to this:

`#1947011350631 .pplr-drop-item._pplr_1.6_kilowatt_evga {}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just managed to solve it myself. Calling it out this way`div#pplr-1947011350631.product-personalizer.pplr_background div.pplr-wrapper.pplr-power-supply span[ class^="pplr-drop-item _pplr_1.6_kilowatt_evga"]`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Calling it out with the code below

`div#pplr-1947011350631.product-personalizer.pplr_background div.pplr-wrapper.pplr-power-supply span[ class^="pplr-drop-item _pplr_1.6_kilowatt_evga"]`